# Custom Widget - Catalog Product Link, with image

Tags: image, magento, widget, product

I'm trying to expand on the standard widget available which creates a basic link to a product.

I want to add the product image to that link.

The widget phtml file resides here:

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\widget\link\link_block.phtml
```

And the widget block file (I think that's the correct terminology) resides here:

```
app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\Link.php
```

I've added a new function to the php file called getProdThumbnail(), which is coded as:

```
public function getProdThumbnail()
{
    if (!$this->_prodThumbnail) {

        if($this->hasStoreId()) {
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore($this->getStoreId());
        } else {
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
        }

        $idPath = explode('/', $this->_getData('id_path'));

        if (isset($idPath[0]) && isset($idPath[1]) && $idPath[0] == 'product') {
        $productId = $idPath[1];
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $this->_prodThumbnail = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(60,60);
        }
    }
    return $this->_prodThumbnail;
}
```

But when the image URL is returned, it points to a placeholder instead of the product thumbnail image:

```
media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/60x60/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg
```

The product has a large, medium, small and thumbnail image assigned.

I'm not sure why, could anyone let me know where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oh wow, now I feel stupid.

- I was loading product from $product_id instead of $productId
- I've posted this on the wrong stack exchange

Doh!